# How to validate an email input box using Ajax and setCustomValidation message

Tags: html, ajax, email, input

I have an email type input text box and would like to use Ajax to query the database once the user types in the email and clicks outside of the box. If email address is available or not available, it should show a setCustomValidation message on the box at run time. How do I do that?? I can't seem to find the solutions on the Internet at all.

Comment: What type of validation?  Jquery-UI?  ASP.NET MVC validation?  Something else?

Comment: I'm using PHP and validating by routing to validation.php page to query the database.